Resize webview in flutter
A url is being shown in WebView and the url contains video and can resize by passing dimension.
Url itself has resized video but WebView not fitting the Url.
WebView
  Widget _buildVideoWebView(
    int index,
    String lotId,
  ) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 140,
      width: 140,
      child: DnaWebViewInterface(
        key: webVideoKey[index],
        url: getDiamondVideoFileUrl(
          lotId,
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

WebView class
class DnaWebViewInterface extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final bool allowInteraction;
  final void Function(double)? onScaleChanged;

  const DnaWebViewInterface({
    super.key,
    required this.url,
    this.allowInteraction = true,
    this.onScaleChanged,
  });

  @override
  State<DnaWebViewInterface> createState() => DnaWebViewInterfaceState();
}

class DnaWebViewInterfaceState extends State<DnaWebViewInterface> {
  final ValueNotifier<double> _progressValueNotifier =
      ValueNotifier<double>(0);
 // Ranges from 0 to 1.
  late final WebViewController _webViewController = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget.url))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          _progressValueNotifier.value = progress / 100;
        },
        onPageFinished: (_) {
          _progressValueNotifier.value = 1;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..setBackgroundColor(CoreColor.neutral100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: WebViewWidget(controller: _webViewController,gestureRecognizers: {
            Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
            ),
          },),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: ValueListenableBuilder(
            valueListenable: _progressValueNotifier,
            builder: (context, value, _) {
              if (value < 1) {
                return Center(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 48,
                    width: 48,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      value: value,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return const SizedBox();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
  void reloadWebView() {
    _webViewController?.reload();
  }
}

Want to fit the video in the below design and using this pub dev webview_flutter


i am not sure i did understand what you mean. can you also share the output you have?

i want to fit the video in the given design, In url by passing height and width we can resize but with webview it is not showing
